# VBA: Copy range of data rows x times

Tags: excel

I need to copy and paste the same information (in order), 1000 times into the same column. The data will run from 1990-2019, separated into quarters...

```
1990 FY1990 FQ11990 31-Jan-90 1 
1990 FY1990 FQ21990 31-Jan-90 2
1990 FY1990 FQ31990 31-Jan-90 3
1990 FY1990 FQ41990 31-Jan-90 4

1990 FY1990 FQ11990 31-Jan-90 1 
1990 FY1990 FQ21990 31-Jan-90 2
etc
etc
```

Is there a code I can write to automate this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are mistaking, I believe the expected result is more like:

```
1990 FY1990 FQ11990 31-Jan-90 1 
1990 FY1990 FQ21990 31-Jan-90 2
1990 FY1990 FQ31990 31-Jan-90 3
1990 FY1990 FQ41990 31-Jan-90 4

1991 FY1991 FQ11991 31-Jan-91 1 
1991 FY1991 FQ21991 31-Jan-91 2
etc
etc
```

In order to do this, you should realise that your expected output looks like:

```
aaaa FYaaaa FQbaaaa 31-Jan-aa b
```

where:
`aaaa` and `aa` are the year, either in four digits or in two
`b` is the quarter number

What's the link between `aaaa` and `aa`? Simple: `aa = MOD(aaaa,100)`.

From there you can start (realising that in Excel, concatenation is extremely simple: `"TotalString" = "Total" & "String"`), so here we go (pseudo-code):

```
offset_number = 0
for aaaa = 1990 to 2019:
  for b = 1 to 4:
    resulting_string = aaaa & " FY" & aaaa & " FQ" & b & aaaa & " 31-Jan-" & MOD(aaaa,100) & " " & b
    Starting_Cell.Offset(offset_number,0) = resulting_string
    offset_number = offset_number + 1
  Next b
Next aaaa
```